# tableview not scrolling smoothly iOS xcode

Tags: tableview, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

Every time i scroll on the tableview and a new cell appears, it get's stuck for like a milli second, that happens every time a new cell appears,.. i tried so many options..

THIS IS WHERE I QUERY MY ARRAY

```
- (void) retrieveStrings {

    PFQuery *retrieveAllPictures = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"String_Pictures"];
    [retrieveAllPictures includeKey:@"string_owner"];
    [retrieveAllPictures whereKey:@"string_boss" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"String" objectId:original_string_objectID]];
    retrieveAllPictures.limit = [loadingNumber intValue];
    [retrieveAllPictures orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [retrieveAllPictures findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

                originalString = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
                [self.StringTable reloadData];

        }
    }];
}
```

THIS IS MY CELL FOR ROW AT INDEX PATH

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"originalStringCell";

    OriginalStringTableViewCell *originalCell = [StringTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    tempObject = [originalString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    userObject = [tempObject objectForKey:@"string_owner"];
    originalTempString = [tempObject objectForKey:@"string_image"];

 [originalTempString getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            originalCell.original_string_image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            CGFloat ImageWidth = ceil(originalCell.original_string_image.image.size.width);
            CGFloat ImageHeight = ceil(originalCell.original_string_image.image.size.height);
            CGFloat NewWidth = ceil ((ImageWidth / ImageWidth) * StringTable.frame.size.width);
            CGFloat NewHeightImageRow = ceil ((ImageHeight / ImageWidth) * StringTable.frame.size.width);

            originalCell.original_string_image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 53, NewWidth, NewHeightImageRow);
            NSLog(@"%f",NewWidth);

            [originalCell.stringIndicator stopAnimating];
            originalCell.stringIndicator.hidden = YES;

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        }
    }];

    return originalCell;

}
```

Comment: never mind people, i have found it myself using SDWebImage

Comment: Even if you figure it out yourself, post the solution as an answer, not an edit.

Comment: Tim Wilkinson, ok thx i have changed it

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution using SDWEBIMAGE.

```
SDWebImageManager *StringPicturemanager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [StringPicturemanager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:originalTempString.    
        options:0
        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
            // progression tracking code
        }
        completed:^(UIImage *SDWStringImage, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
            if (SDWStringImage) {
                NSLog(@"JAAAAAA %@", SDWStringImage);
                originalCell.original_string_image.image = SDWStringImage;
                CGFloat ImageWidth = ceil(originalCell.original_string_image.image.size.width);
                CGFloat ImageHeight = ceil(originalCell.original_string_image.image.size.height);
                CGFloat NewWidth = ceil ((ImageWidth / ImageWidth) * StringTable.frame.size.width);
                CGFloat NewHeightImageRow = ceil ((ImageHeight / ImageWidth) * StringTable.frame.size.width);
                originalCell.original_string_image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 53, NewWidth, NewHeightImageRow);
                NSLog(@"%f",NewWidth);
                [originalCell.stringIndicator stopAnimating];
                originalCell.stringIndicator.hidden = YES;
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                }
            }];
```